# What is the best technology for drawing trees and graphs?

Tags: tree, draw, tikz

What is the easiest, clearest way to draw graphs and trees for CS theory assignments?

I am not happy with any of these solutions:

- text-based: ugly
- tikz latex package: cumbersome for larger trees
- Adobe Illustrator: time-consuming

Has anyone written software specifically for this task?

Thanks!

Comment: NetworkX with Graphviz is kind of nice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1.) http://www.graphviz.org/ is the easiest for drawing directed and undirected graphs. You just provide a list of nodes, edges and labels in the proper syntax, and GraphViz will spit out an image.There are various front-end programs that provide a nicer interface to generate the GraphViz code.

2.) http://www.sagemath.org/ (it's open source and can draw weighted directed graphs)

3.)  http://sourceforge.net/projects/treeform/

4.)   http://www.mi.sanu.ac.rs/newgraph/

5.)   http://www.conceptdraw.com/products/drawing-tool/

6.)   http://rw4.cs.uni-sb.de/~sander/html/gstools.html (collection of graph drawing tools details)

Answer (score 3):

you might find [Dia](https://live.gnome.org/Dia) a helpful tool for all kinds of CS charts, graphs, and trees.